# Sorting DataTable jquery excluding whitespace in the text fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

**My scenario:**

I am trying to sort date column of the table which uses `DataTable` jquery plugin and I have sorted the table but with the text fields having white-spaces. Hence, when I sort "**ASC**" order, then the empty text fields will occupy at first. This should not happen. I want to sort the table excluding the empty text boxes.

**I tried the following code:**

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
"customdatesort-pre": function (formElement) {
    // returns the "weight" of a cell value
    var r, x;
    var a = $(formElement).val();

    if (a === null || a === "") {
        // for empty cells: weight is a "special" value which needs special handling
        r = false;
    } else {
        // otherwise: weight is the "time value" of the date
        x = a.split("/");
        r = +new Date(+x[2], +x[1] - 1, +x[0]);
    }
    //console.log("[PRECALC] " + a + " becomes " + r);
    return r;
},
"customdatesort-asc": function (a, b) {
    // return values are explained in Array.prototype.sort documentation
    if (a === false && b === false) {
        // if both are empty cells then order does not matter
        return 0;
    } else if (a === false) {
        // if a is an empty cell then consider a greater than b
        return 1;
    } else if (b === false) {
        // if b is an empty cell then consider a less than b
        return -1;
    } else {
        // common sense
        return a - b;
    }
},
"customdatesort-desc": function (a, b) {
    if (a === false && b === false) {
        return 0;
    } else if (a === false) {
        return 1;
    } else if (b === false) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return b - a;
    }
}
});
```

**Problem I found with this code:**

In the above code, you can see the `"customdatesort-pre": function (formElement)` . The parameter `formElement` is taking only the empty values and not the textboxes with some date values.

**What I need:**

I need to sort the date columns excluding the empty textboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With custom sorting `pre` obsoletes `asc` and `desc`. If you have defined a `pre` then the `asc` and `desc` methods will never be called. `pre` is meant as an optimisation feature, it is called once for each cell, and then the internal sorter will use that result for sorting. See [this thread on datatables.net](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/21104/custom-sorting-asc-desc-not-called-when-pre-is-present).

Instead you could place the `pre` function code outside the custom sort literal and call it from within the `asc` and `desc` methods :

```
customdatesortPre = function (formElement) {
  //customdatesort-pre code
}
jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
  "customdatesort-asc": function (a, b) {
    a = customdatesortPre(a), b = customdatesortPre(b);
    ...
  },
  "customdatesort-desc": function (a, b) {
    a = customdatesortPre(a), b = customdatesortPre(b);
    ...
  }
});
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/9j9gpsrn/**